# Java scanner string with spaces

Tags: java

So my program runs fine but when i type in items with spaces its throws a java.util.InputMismatchException. so i changed all the kb.next() to kb.nextLine() but the problem im having with that is for example: the add section, as soon as it prints **Please enter the title that you would like to add.**, it doesnt let me input anything, it just skips to the next line and prints **Please enter the have value of the item that you would like to add.**

```
System.out.println( "Please enter the title that you would like to add." );
                    title = kb.next();

 System.out.println( "Please enter the want value of the item that you would like to add." );
                    wantValue = kb.nextInt();

 System.out.println( "Please enter the have value of the item that you would like to add." );
                     haveValue = kb.nextInt();
```

.

```
package assignment3;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question1 
{
    static SortedList inventory;

    //main 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        inventory = new SortedList();
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String command, title;
        int wantValue, haveValue;

        do
        {
            System.out.println("\n              MAIN MENU");
            System.out.println( "H. Provide a summary of available commands");
            System.out.println( "L. List the entire inventory." );
            System.out.println( "I. Display Inventory information for a specific title.");
            System.out.println( "A. Add a new title to Inventory.");
            System.out.println( "M. Modify the want value of a specific title.");
            System.out.println( "S. Sell an item");
            System.out.println( "O. Write a purchase order for additional DVD's");
            System.out.println( "R. Write a return order.");
            System.out.println( "Q. Quit the program.");
            command = kb.next();

            //If the user need a summary of available commands. 
            if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("H"))
            {
                System.out.println( "H (help), provides a summary of available commands." );
                System.out.println( "L (list), list the entire inventory." );
                System.out.println( "I<title> (inquire), Display theinventory information for a specific title." );
                System.out.println( "A<title> (add), add a new title to the existing inventory." );
                System.out.println( "M<title> (modify), modify the want value of a specific title." );
                System.out.println( "S<title> (sell), sell an item, decrease have value of that item by 1." );
                System.out.println( "O (order), write an order for additional items so have value = want value." );
                System.out.println( "R (return), return extras so have value = want value." );
                System.out.println( "Q (quit), quit the program." );
            }

            //If the user want the inventory info on a specific title
            else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("I"))
            {
                System.out.println( "Please enter the title that you would like to inquire." );
                title = kb.next();
                //Search through the inventory
                for(int i =1; i<=inventory.size();i++)
                {
                    StockItem item = (StockItem)inventory.get(i);
                    //if a matching title is found
                    if((item.getTitle()).equals(title))
                    {
                        //print out the item
                        String s=  item.toString();
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                }
            }

            //If the user want a list the entire inventory.
            else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))
            {
                //Search through the inventory
                for(int i =1; i <=inventory.size(); i++)
                {
                    StockItem item = (StockItem)inventory.get(i);
                    //print out the item
                    String s=  item.toString();
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }

            //If the user want to add a new item to the inventory
            else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
            {
                System.out.println( "Please enter the title that you would like to add." );
                title = kb.next();

                System.out.println( "Please enter the want value of the item that you would like to add." );
                wantValue = kb.nextInt();

                 System.out.println( "Please enter the have value of the item that you would like to add." );
                 haveValue = kb.nextInt();

                 //Add the new item to the inventory
                 StockItem NewItem = new StockItem(title,haveValue,wantValue);
                 inventory.sortedAdd(NewItem);
                 String s=  NewItem.toString();
                System.out.println(s);

            }

            //If the user want to change an item in the inventory
            else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
            {
                System.out.println( "Please enter the title of the DVD you would like to modify" );
                title = kb.next();

                //Search through the inventory
                for(int i =1; i<=inventory.size();i++)
                {
                    StockItem item = (StockItem)inventory.get(i);

                    //If an item is found, print it out and ask the user for a new want value
                    if((item.getTitle()).equals(title))
                    {
                        System.out.println( "Title: " + item.getTitle());
                        System.out.println( "Want value: " + item.getWant());
                        System.out.println( "Have value: " + item.getHave());

                        System.out.println( "Please enter the new want value for " + item.getTitle());
                        int newWantValue = kb.nextInt();

                        item.setWant(newWantValue);

                        String s=  item.toString();
                        System.out.println(s);

                    }
                }
            }

            //If the user want to sell an item for the inventory
            else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
            {
                System.out.println( "Please enter the title of the DVD you would like to sell" );
                title = kb.next();

                //Search through the inventory
                for(int i =1; i<=inventory.size();i++)
                {
                    StockItem item = (StockItem)inventory.get(i);
                    if((item.getTitle()).equals(title))
                    {
                        //if there is non in the inventory, add the user to the waiting list
                        if(item.getHave() == 0)
                        {
                            System.out.println( "We are currently out of " + item.getTitle());
                            System.out.println( "Please add customer to waiting list");

                            System.out.println( "Please enter customer's last name");
                            String lastName = kb.next();
                            System.out.println( "Please enter customer's first name");
                            String firstName = kb.next();
                            System.out.println( "Please enter customer's phone number");
                            String phone = kb.next();
                            item.addToWaitingList(lastName,firstName,phone);            
                        }

                        else{
                            //decrease the have by 1
                                item.setHave(item.getHave()-1);                     
                            }

                        String s=  item.toString();
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                }
            }

            //if the user want to print out a purchase order 
            else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("O"))
            {
                //String s = "  Purchase Order: \n";
                System.out.println("Purchase Order:");
                for(int i =1; i<=inventory.size(); i++)
                {
                    StockItem item = (StockItem)inventory.get(i);
                    if(item.getHave()<item.getWant())
                    {
                        int ToBePurchased = item.getWant()+item.getSizeofWaitingList()- item.getHave();

                        String  s =  "\n Title: "+ item.getTitle() +"\t"+"Number in stock: "+ item.getHave()+"\t"+"Number of Wants:"+item.getWant()+"\t"+" Number of customers on waiting List : "
                                +item.getSizeofWaitingList()+"\t"+"Number to be Purchased: " +ToBePurchased ;
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                }
            }

            //if the user want to a return order
            else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
            {
                //Search through the inventory
                for(int i =1; i<=inventory.size();i++)
                {
                    StockItem item = (StockItem)inventory.get(i);

                        if(item.getHave()>(item.getWant()+item.getSizeofWaitingList()))
                        {
                            int returnValue = item.getHave() - item.getWant() - item.getSizeofWaitingList();
                            item.setHave(returnValue);

                            String s=  item.toString();
                            System.out.println(s);

                        }
                        if(item.getHave() == 0 && item.getWant() == 0 && item.getSizeofWaitingList() == 0)
                        {
                            inventory.sortedRemove(item);

                            String s=  item.toString();
                            System.out.println(s);
                        }
                }

            }

        } while (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint and see what's the value of `title` variable when this happens

Comment: I actually got it to work by creating a new input scanner after every if statement that requires a user's input.

Thanks for your idea too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, i added a new input scanner **Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);** after every if statement that requires a user's input. instead of having a global one.